# Are there any free reverse delay AU plugins

Tags: logic-pro, plugins, macosx

I'm looking for a free reverse delay AU plugin.  Specifically something that emulates the delay on the Boss DD-6 delay pedal, which does a reverse delay on phrases in real time.

Comment: For Windows or Mac?

Comment: For Mac, I'm using Logic

Answer (score 2):

you might find what you are looking for in [audiomastermind](http://www.audiomastermind.com/browse-delay__echo-5886996-1.html), i think [Deloizer free VST Plugin](http://andreas.smartelectronix.com/index.php?nav=9&p=2&kat=0)  would satisfy your needs

Comment: Logic uses AU plugins. You'd need a wrapper or translator to use VSTs, unfortunately.

Comment: Windows Ableton Live user here. Thanks for the reply ;-)

Answer (score 2):

On the Pedalboard Plugin in Logic the Tru-Tape Delay Pedal has a reverse delay feature

Comment: logic is not a free product so this answer is not very helpful. sorry.

Comment: OP is already using Logic.  This answer does indeed offer a solution to the question.